# How to make selected tab in terminal more prominent

Tags: themes, gnome-terminal

Something about the color scheme changed in 11.04, and now it's very difficult for me to tell which tab is the selected one.

[image]

On my screen, the colors look more similar the further down I slouch in my chair (i.e. angle of view).

If I change the color scheme the problem is solved, but that solution is too extreme for me. Is there a way to just change the color of the selected tab in terminal, or otherwise make it more prominent?

**UPDATE**: In 12.10 the accepted solution doesn't work. Can anyone fix it?

Comment: This has been reported as a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-themes/+bug/761660

Comment: I confirm,  In 12.10 the accepted solution doesn't work. Bug opened here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/762349

Comment: Neither of these solutions is working for me in 12.04. Any ideas?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

For 12.10–15.04 you can create a CSS theme for GTK 3.0 as explained in this [comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-themes/+bug/762349/comments/10) by Kees (kees-vanveen) on the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-themes/+bug/762349) posted above by Alessio.

1. Create the file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`
2. Paste this as the contents using your desired color:

   ```
   TerminalWindow .notebook tab:active {
       background-color: #def;
   }
   ```
3. Close all Terminal windows and relaunch the application to see the change.

Comment: Works great -- thanks!  As a reminder to anyone trying this solution, you'll need to log out and log back in before changes take effect.

Comment: Just closing all terminal windows and reopening a new session worked for me.

Comment: @SamKing, you mean logging out and again in to the terminal or the whole (X) session? Because just closing and reopening the terminal worked for me (13.10).

Comment: This works in 13.04 too.

Comment: Confirming this works through 14.10. As long as gnome-terminal uses gtk-3, unless they change the spec this should always be a solution.

Comment: For completeness, if I want to make the inactive tabs dimmer (in 14.04 everything's white-ish), what are the CSS selectors for them?

Comment: Ah; you just lop off `:active`, but you still need to style the `:active` pseudoclass as there doesn't seem to be any rules there by default.

Comment: You can test the change without closing all terminal windows by starting a new terminal with `gnome-terminal --disable-factory`

Comment: This isn't having any affect for me on 14.10. Anything else that could go wrong?

Comment: confirm works on 14.04

Comment: @SamBrightman Make sure you are using Gnome Terminal and close all terminal windows after making the change.

Comment: Yes, this works (tested on 15.04).

Comment: This works fine for `Gnome Terminal`. Any idea how to do this for `Terminator` as well? I am on 14.04. Thanks!

Comment: @HRJ Ask a new question to get visibility. Link to this one to let people know you're talking about a different terminal program and don't mark it dupe.

Comment: For a better look, try this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/406816/421047

Answer (score 17):

I'm not that much of a theme hacker, but here's a quick fix:

Create or edit the file `~/.gtkrc-2.0` to include the following:

```
style "gnome_terminal_notebook"
{
  fg[NORMAL] = "#00ff00"
}

widget "*TerminalWindow.*.GtkNotebook*" style "gnome_terminal_notebook"
```

This will turn the text color of the active tab green. Not very beautiful, but should give you a start.

You could also lighten up the highlighted tab by replacing the *fg* line with:

```
bg[NORMAL] = shade (1.25, "#3c3b37")
```

The downside: this will also make the inner borders brighter.

Note: This will influence every theme you choose in the appearance properties, so don't forget to undo those changes when using another theme.

Comment: This workaround works perfectly! You can use #4c4b47 for an even brighter background.

Comment: This suggestion does not work on 12.10   Can anyone confirm it does ?

Comment: @ScottStensland - See [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/252192/18031) for a solution that works on 12.10.

Comment: Works for gtk-2.0 based terminal, like my: MATE Terminal 1.8.1 / MATE Desktop Environment 1.8.2 / Ubuntu 14.04 / Kernel Linux 4.2.0-27-generic. Also refer to [this](https://weishi.github.io/blog/2014/09/27/change-tab-color-in-terminator-and-ubuntu-terminal/) for `bg[ACTIVE]` `fg[ACTIVE]` etc.

Answer (score 4):

Using Ubuntu's *warm grey* in https://design.ubuntu.com/brand/colour-palette, this is a small variation of David's:

```
TerminalWindow .notebook tab {
    background-color: #e2e0dd;
}

TerminalWindow .notebook tab:active {
    background-color: #f2f1f0;
}
```

The color of other tabs here is slightly darker.

Answer (score 1):

You can hack the theme and change colors that way. I did that years ago when a theme I otherwise liked didn't have enough contrast.

Themes installed system-wide live in `/usr/share/themes`, while your own themes live in `~/.themes`. If the theme you're modifying is a system-wide theme, I suggest copying it to `~/.themes` and renaming it before making changes. Otherwise, your changes will get overwritten the next time the package responsible for those files gets upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 16.04, create a file named ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css, and place the following into it:

```
TerminalWindow .notebook tab:active {
    background-color: #b0c0f0;
}
```

Credit: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/highlighting-the-active-tab-in-gnome-terminal/

Comment: This is the same as the accepted answer.