# In XUbuntu there are black unreadable tabs in GTK applications such as gEdit

Tags: xubuntu, themes, xfce

I'm using XFCE in Ubuntu 14.04.   When I open gEdit, the tabs at the top are unreadable:

[image: black tabs in gEdit]

Having done some research, it appears that this is because gEdit is a GTK 2.0 application and this problem manifests itself if the theme you are using does not have specific workarounds in it for GTK 2.0 applications.

Here is what I have tried so far:

- [This forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2056919) seems to indicate that using the Greybird theme would solve the problem.  The above screenshot was taken with Greybird, and it did not solve the problem.
- [This appears to be the same problem asked on StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819756/gedit-in-lxde-black-bar)  None of the answers are very helpful.
- [This is a similar question asked here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253880/can-i-change-the-color-of-tabs-in-gedit) but is about tabs that are very dark but not black: [image]
- [This forum thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=116451) suggest creating a configuration file for a fallback theme for GTK 2.0 applications.  Creating this configuration file did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem only exists on a Ubuntu installation with a later installed xubuntu-desktop. **If you use only Xubuntu without the unity-desktop this problem does not exist**. However, if I choose the Radiance theme the problem seems to go away.

[image] 
[image]

I have restarted the system to be sure it is permanently.

Comment: How do you get that appearance dialog?  I have been choosing themes from "Settings" -> "Window Manager" which looks much different and doesn't have "Radiance" listed.

Comment: Found it under "Settings" -> "Appearance".  I'm not sure how it differs from the theme selection for the window manager, but it does seem to solve the problem.  Of all the themes listed there, only "Raleigh" has the problem in gedit.