# gnome-terminal active window background color

Tags: gnome-terminal, focus

In tmux, if tmux.conf has lines

```
set -g window-style 'bg=colour237'
set -g window-active-style 'bg=colour232'
```

Then the active pane will have a different background color than the others.

Can this be done with gnome-terminal *windows*? Say i have 2 terminal windows, one snapped to the right of the screen and one to the left. Could the active one always have a different terminal profile?

Or could inactive terminal windows have a different background defined in `.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`? I know you can change [tab colors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40332/how-to-make-selected-tab-in-terminal-more-prominent) in that file, but dont know anything else about what you can do with that file.