# how to change the color of current active terminal title bar color when switching between tabs

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal, colors

I am using ubuntu 14.04.
I have to open multiple terminal tabs while working.
As I open more and more terminal tabs, It is becomes very difficult to identify the current working tab.
I like to know how to change the color (say red title bar) for the active terminal tab

Comment: The answer is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40332/how-to-make-selected-tab-in-terminal-more-prominent) Also see [Gnome-terminal tabs: no contrast between active and inactive tabs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355297/gnome-terminal-tabs-no-contrast-between-active-and-inactive-tabs)

Answer (score 5):

What about this way?

1. Pick a color in http://www.color-hex.com/
2. Create a file

> vi .config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css

3. Change the content of this like following

   ```
   TerminalWindow .notebook tab:active {
   background-color: #ffce00; // what you want(or pick)
   }
   ```